# Array Value assign in java array?

Tags: java

I am trying to assign value for an array like this way:

```
int x[] = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i]++;
        System.out.println(x[i]);
    }
```

But it's return only 1 for each array position. Can anyone explain me how it works?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Sorry for my bad question. Actually my head was hanged at that moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer primitives are `0` by default. The array itself is populated with zero values. Incrementing each value populates the array values with....`1`

Read: [Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: It was actually very simple question. I understand the question. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

The default value for `int` primitives is 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behaviour

```
int x[] = new int[10];
```

=> each array postion is assigned 0

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i]++; // add 1 to the position i 
  System.out.println(x[i]); // => print 1
 }
```